# How to show bubbles or square at the point of intercetion in line chart of google chats

Tags: google-visualization

I have created a line chart using google charts and i want to show bubbles or squares at the point of intersection of the chart.
How do i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have checked google api and found the solutions as below which is working as expected for me:-

```
     > pointSize: 6,
     > pointShape: { type: 'circle' },
```